# Usage of "aber"

Tags: word-usage, conjunction, particle

Why is "aber" used in this context?

> Darf ich dich zu einem Kaffee einladen?
>      – **Aber** ja, sehr gern.

Comment: It has the connotation of "of course", "without question", "no problem", "it's a pleasure" or "glad to help", depending on the context. Especially if someone asks for a favor, this answer reassures the person that you are not bothered at all by that request.

Comment: @Landei: That makes perfect sense, thank you.

Comment: Hey Gigili, your previous user image was nicer! ;-)

Comment: In my opinion, the `Aber` in the sentence above indicates a little bit of pleasant surprise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's like saying "But sure, you're welcome!". It probably means "You might believe it's not ok, BUT it is"

Comment: Even the English translation doesn't make sense to me. I wouldn't say "but sure" despite there was a conversation going on that I have a problem but sure.

Comment: Simply that's it.

Answer (score 3):

In diesem Fall steht `aber` nicht als Konjunktion, sondern als **Modalpartikel/Abtönungspartikel**.

Die Duden Grammatik (hier 7. Auflage) gibt nähere Auskunft:

> *(§ 870)* **Partikeln** kommen besonders häufig in der gesprochenen
>   Sprache vor und erfüllen ganz unterschiedliche Funktionen:
>
> - als *Gradpartikeln* geben sie Auskunft über die Intensität von    Eigenschaften
> - als *Fokuspartikeln* heben sie bestimmte Teile eines Satzes hervor
> - als *Negationspartikeln* verneinen sie einen Satz oder Teilsatz
> - als *Abtönungspartikeln* geben sie Auskunft über die subjektive Einstellung, die Haltung des Sprechers zum Sachverhalt
> - als *Gesprächspartikeln* steuern sie den Ablauf von Dialogen
> - als *Interjektionen* dienen sie dem Ausdruck von Emotionen
> - als *Onomatopoetika* imitieren sie Geräusche.

Es ist typisch für Partikeln, "dass sie in verschiedenen Klassen der Nichtflektierbaren bzw. der Partikeln vorkommen können". Als Beispiel wird u. a. angeführt:

> Wir wollten kommen, *aber* der Zug fiel aus. (Konjunktion) – Das ist *aber* schön! (Abtönungspartikel)

§ 875 bezieht sich explizit auf die **Abtönungspartikeln/Modalpartikeln**:

> (...) Abtönungspartikel kommen besonders häufig in der gesprochenen
>   Sprache vor und sind dort keineswegs, wie früher angenommen, unnütze
>   Füllwörter. Sie drücken sehr differenziert Einstellungen, Annahmen,
>   Bewertungen und Erwartungen des Sprechers bezüglich des geäußerten
>   Sachverhalts, teilweise auch seine Erwartungen an den Hörer aus.
>   Abtönungspartikeln beziehen sich auf den gesamten Satz. (...)
>  Die
>   häufigsten Abtönunspartikeln sind: *ja, denn, wohl, doch, aber, nur,
>   halt, eben, mal, schon, auch, bloß, eigentlich, etwa, nicht,
>   vielleicht, ruhig*. (...)

Im Beispiel der Frage steht `aber` in Kombination mit dem Gesprächspartikel (hier: Antwortpartikel) `ja`. Sein Gebrauch gibt der Antwort eine besondere Betonung; diese wirkt dadurch etwas emphatischer als ein einfaches "Ja, sehr gern."

(Der korrekte Plural von *Partikel* lautet übrigens *Partikel****n***, so der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Partikel_Wortart_Reliquie). Umso verwunderlicher, dass in der Duden Grammatik sowohl *Partikeln* als auch *Partikel* als Pluralform Verwendung findet.)

Comment: "die Partikeln" ist der korrekte Plural zu "die Partikel" (eine Wortklasse). Der Plural "die Partikel" ist nur richtig für "das Partikel" (im Sinne von "Teilchen").

Comment: Genau. Ich hätte vielleicht noch erwähnen sollen, dass nicht nur im zuletzt zitierten Absatz, sondern auch in den Überschriften in der Duden Grammatik immer wieder das *n* fehlt.

Answer (score 0):

In this case *aber* is used as *of course.*

This use is less frequent than the use as *but.*